# Force a break in a items control with wrap panel template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, wrappanel

I've got an interesting problem I've been trying to solve.  Basically I have an items control that uses a `WrapPanel` as it's `ItemsPanel` to simulate a paragraph built from several bound strings.  However there are times where I need to force a break, like when I start a new paragraph, however putting a break into the `TextBlock` `DateTemplate` does not actually put a break into the parent wrap panel.  Here is the code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Fragments}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                Text="{Binding}"/> <!--If this text has a break it won't 
                                        propagate that break to the wrap panel,
                                        but instead just in this text block which
                                        causes the formatting to look wrong-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here is a simple definition for fragments that will show what I am talking about:

```
Fragments = new ObservableCollection<string>();
Fragments.Add("This is");
Fragments.Add("the first line, ");
Fragments.Add("it is very long and will drift to the ");
Fragments.Add("second line naturally since it is controlled by a wrap panel");
Fragments.Add("\n\r This I want to force to the line below where the line above ends");
Fragments.Add("rapid \n\r new \n\r lines");
```

[image]

I would like this to flow as paragraphs that just continue to get concatenated, but honor the manual breaks when they are run into.  Like this:

```
This is the first line, it is very long and will drift to the second line 
naturally since it is controlled by a wrap panel.
This I want to force to the line below where the line above ends.
rapid
new
lines
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not concatenating the strings and then binding it to a simple text box?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not concatenating the strings and then binding it to a simple text box?

Comment: by "Break" do you mean "NewLine"?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 yes newline.

Comment: @Kenneth The strings can be dynamically updated, so each word needs to be bound separately.

Comment: I know that in xaml you have to use hex code for NewLine so if you are using `\n\r` try using `&#x0a;`, its a bit hard to tell without seeing the population of `Fragments`, can you show that code (or just an example of it so I can test)

Comment: @sa_ddam213 edited some sample test data to show what's happening

Comment: I think you just need to set your `WrapPanel` `Orientation="Vertical"`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 That makes every word on a new line, I just want it to be a new line when it needs to wrap, or when it sees an explicit new line character.

Comment: Really, works ok here, are you able to post a picture of what you are expecting it to look like, I don't think I understand what you are tring to do, Could you not just use `StackPanel` as the `ItemsPanel` or just use a `TextBox` and populate the `Lines` property instead of using `ItemsControl`?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I can come up with a better picture of what I want when I get home, but say I have 10 single words in a string, I want those to all show up on the same wrapped line.  It should only break when I give it a specific break, or it needs to wrap.  Having it be vertical would always put each entry on a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would chuck the ItemsControl and use the Inlines collection of a textblock instead. Unfortunately you cannot bind your collection of strings directly, because `TextBlock.Inlines` is not a dependency property, but it's not hard to work around that with an attached dependency property:

I have also added support for propagation of the CollectionChanged event, so adding a string to `ViewModel.Fragments` will update the textblock. Removing will work too, although with the limitation that the first Fragment matching the string will be removed.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock local:FlowSupport.Fragments="{Binding Fragments}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="10" Background="Beige" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _fragments;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Fragments { get { return _fragments; } set { _fragments = value; OnPropertyChanged("Fragments"); } }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Fragments = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Fragments.Add("This is ");
        Fragments.Add("the first line, ");
        Fragments.Add("it is very long and will drift to the ");
        Fragments.Add("second line naturally since it is controlled by a wrap panel");
        Fragments.Add("\nThis I want to force to the line below where the line above ends\n");
        Fragments.Add("rapid \nnew \nlines");
    }
}
```

FlowSupport:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public static class FlowSupport
    {
        private static Dictionary<TextBlock, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler> _collChangedHandlers = new Dictionary<TextBlock,NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler>();

        public static ObservableCollection<string> GetFragments(TextBlock tb) { return (ObservableCollection<string>)tb.GetValue(FragmentsProperty); }
        public static void SetFragments(TextBlock tb, ObservableCollection<string> value) { tb.SetValue(FragmentsProperty, value); }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FragmentsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Fragments", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(FlowSupport), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>(), OnFragmentsChanged));

        private static void OnFragmentsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var tb = d as TextBlock;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                CreateCollectionChangedHandler(tb); // create handler, once per textblock

                tb.Inlines.Clear();
                var oldInlines = e.OldValue as ObservableCollection<string>;
                if (oldInlines != null)
                {
                    oldInlines.CollectionChanged -= _collChangedHandlers[tb];
                }
                var inlines = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<string>;
                if (inlines != null)
                {
                    inlines.CollectionChanged += _collChangedHandlers[tb];

                    foreach (string s in inlines)
                        tb.Inlines.Add(s);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void CreateCollectionChangedHandler(TextBlock tb)
        {
            if (!_collChangedHandlers.ContainsKey(tb))
            {
                _collChangedHandlers.Add(tb, (s1, e1) =>
                {
                    if (e1.NewItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (string text in e1.NewItems)
                            tb.Inlines.Add(text);
                    }
                    if (e1.OldItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (string text in e1.OldItems)
                        {
                            Inline inline = tb.Inlines.FirstOrDefault(i => ((Run)i).Text == text);
                            if (inline != null)
                                tb.Inlines.Remove(inline);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll give it a try when I get home.

Comment: Hmm, the only problem with this solution was with item's control and wrap panel I could control specifics of each word, ie boldness text color...etc.  Is there anyway to achieve that effect anymore with this approach?

Comment: Never mind I figured out a work-around, I can add `Run` objects to the inline and set the properties within.  Just 1 more problem, the OnFragmentsChanged is only firing on load, and not when the collection actually changes.

Comment: Actually I see the problem, it would work if I added or subtracted things from the list, but actually I'm only changing things in the list, I need that to somehow fire the change events and I'm set.

Comment: OK, I got it figured out, thanks for the help, the textblock inlines property is a much better solution for what I'm doing.  Enjoy the 50 rep.